# synthesis of 'module Rocket' with CONFIG=DefaultSmallConfig

Tags: rocket-chip

I'm trying to synthesize the rocket core (1 core without cache) for 22nm technology with DefaultSmallConfig generated verilog. I see timing violations(huge negative slack -250ns) even at 200Mhz (5ns) but the published literature say that it has achieved timing upto 1Ghz. I wonder where I'm going wrong in synthesis step.

any pointers would be great help to fix the issue.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure for what you're synthesizing,

If you're synthesizing it for fpga;It might not possible. 
Go for smaller architecture eg. tiny core without l2 caches,even for tiny core it's difficult to achieve 250 ns for ultrascale FPGAs.